# How to capture audio data while another app is recording in Android?

Tags: android, audio

I'm writing an app to recognize human voice. The voice recognizer module (integrated as a .so file) is from a third-party company.

**My purpose:**

When I calls the voice recognizer module to record audio from microphone, I can capture the audio data in real time. I need the real-time audio data to display a dynamic waveform on the screen.

**My problem:**

The microphone is an exclusive device, i.e. when one module has occupied the microphone, another module cannot occupy it simultaneously.

Is there a way to solve it?